# SFML Networking | Sending objects containing other objects over sf::Packets cause null data

Tags: c++, networking, sfml

I am trying to send map data to a client, which takes the form of multiple vectors containing coordinates of the map's tiles. The whole map structure can be reduced to something like this (not actual code, but I reproduced the problem using this too) :

```
struct Tile {
    sf::Vector3<int> coords;
};

struct Map {
    Tile tiles[4];
};
```

Then, I use these operators to add this type of objects to a `sf::Packet` :

```
sf::Packet& operator<<(sf::Packet& packet, sf::Vector3<int> vec) {
    return packet << vec.x << vec.y << vec.z;
}

sf::Packet& operator>>(sf::Packet& packet, sf::Vector3<int> vec) {
    return packet >> vec.x >> vec.y >> vec.z;
}

sf::Packet& operator<<(sf::Packet& packet, Tile test) {
    return packet << test.coords;
}

sf::Packet& operator>>(sf::Packet& packet, Tile test) {
    return packet >> test.coords;
}

sf::Packet& operator<<(sf::Packet& packet, Map test) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        packet << test.tiles[i];
    }
    return packet;
}

sf::Packet& operator>>(sf::Packet& packet, Map test) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        packet >> test.tiles[i];
    }
    return packet;
}
```

Up to here, there shouldn't be any problem : the map must be deserialized to 4 tiles, which must be deserialised to a `sf::Vector3<int>` itself.

Then comes the sending :

```
Tile test;
test.coords.x = 42;
test.coords.y = 34;
test.coords.z = 43;

Map test3;
test3.tiles[0] = test;

sf::Packet packet;
packet << test3;

sock.send(packet);
```

This code works very well (I checked the content of the `packet` with GDB, data is indeed the same). The reception code works well too server-side :

```
sf::Packet packet;
sock.receive(packet);
Map test;
cout << "packet received" << endl;
```

Checking the content of the packet (still with GDB) gives the same thing as when it was sent. The contents of `test` are random (which is normal, because it hasn't been initialised yet).

The real problem happens when deserializing the actual packet data to the `test` variable :

```
if(packet >> test) {
    cout << test.tiles[0].coords.x;
} else {
    cout << "fail" << endl;
}
```

The result printed is 0. The deserialisation did well (no "fail" appearing in the console), but data is incorrect. Inspecting `test`'s contents with GDB reveals every element its arrays are 0s. Here's GDB's output :

```
(gdb) print test
$1 = {tiles = {{coords = {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}}, {coords = {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}}, {coords = {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}}, {coords = {
        x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}}}}
```

What could be the cause of this ? I am very sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I really can't get why.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to understand why this did not work.
The answer, was, of course, extremely stupid, and typical of a silly C++ beginner :D.

Using the operator functions without passing the objects by reference was not having a single chance to work (as the variable's content would stay in the operator function and not be changed).

So, changing this :

```
sf::Packet& operator>>(sf::Packet& packet, Map test) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        packet >> test.tiles[i];
    }
    return packet;
}
```

to this :

```
sf::Packet& operator>>(sf::Packet& packet, Map& test) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        packet >> test.tiles[i];
    }
    return packet;
}
```

worked much better :)